# Regex matching hyphen and comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to match numbers using regex:

1. Can contain hyphen in between
2. Can contain both hyphen and comma

tried:

```
[0-9-]+    
[0-9]+[-]?:[-N]?[0-9]
```

Sample valid input:

```
60-55-1
79-0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26
```

Answer (score 6):

So you mean, like, `[0-9,-]+` for instance?

Comment: Okay, but the whole point of `[]` is that it can be any of the characters.

Comment: But it doesn't enforce a hyphen.  Too bad the OP didn't mention that in the question.  (FirmView: [please edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11497265/edit) to include any criteria.  Kolink's answer IS the correct answer to your question.)

Answer (score 2):

Building on Kolink's answer (which was correct as far as the question went), and assuming `,23` and `79-` are not valid:

```
^[0-9][0-9,-]*-[0-9,-]*[0-9]$
```

This requires the string to start with a digit, contain any number of valid characters followed by a hyphen, then any other number of valid characters, ending up with a digit.  Note that this is simple BRE (not ERE or PREG), so it will work with every regex parser.

If the samples I mentioned *are* in fact valid, please say so.

Comment: That allows things like `12-,34`.  Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

This will match what you are looking for

```
[0-9]+(?:[-,]?[0-9]+)*
```

It will get any number pattern followed by an optional string with dashes and commas followed by more numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
(-)?[0-9]+((,|-)[0-9]+)*
```

I think this can meet your need.